# Which Windows GUI frameworks are currently worth learning?

Tags: c#, java, windows, user-interface

I'm planning to write a Windows app to help myself with some exploratory testing tasks (note taking, data generation, defect logging) and I've got stuck at the early stage of choosing a framework/language. My sole experience is with web development and from what I can see, WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, Swing etc are all simultaneously obsolete and thriving depending on who you ask.

While my main aim is to create the app, obviously I'd like to learn something useful while doing so rather than picking up skills with something that's never going to be seen on a project at work. Which Java or C# frameworks would people recommend learning?

Comment: WPF is obsolete?

Comment: @pezcode: Haven't you heard? Metro/WinRT is the **cool new in thing** now.

Comment: @BoltClock Eventually everything will render obsolete, I'm still waiting for Html to render obsolete, but it's probably not going to happen in my lifetime:) As for Wpf it will remain for a while since Metro apps are not meant to replace everything. A lot of people skipped vista which resulted in a very long life for Xp. This will probably will happen a lot with Win8, unless they will start giving away touchscreens:)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Note:** consider when this answer was posted (2012). Since then, things have changed a bit, for example [Silverlight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight) has been deprecated.

---

### Native Applications

**For employment**:
Well, nowadays most companies (at least most companies from Oman and the UAE, where I live) are slowly migrating to the cloud. However there are still some opportunities for native app development. The most demanding framework nowadays, is, ( no.. not [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) ), it's [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms)!

Why plain old Windows Forms instead of the awesome WPF? One reason, *legacy apps*. Nowadays most companies only start small scale GUI Application projects, mainly Business applications. For that, WPF will be very expensive since they already have a work-force experienced in Windows Forms, and a lot of legacy code, however for WPF they will have to create a new code-base, and that's pretty risky. So the best thing to keep you employed is Windows Forms.

**For new projects**: However, if by 'worth learning', you mean, new, ambitious and glamorous. Then WPF may be the best choice for you. It depends on what your requirements are, really.

### The Cloud

Now, for the cloud. Java FX and Silverlight are both currently head to head. However Java FX may have an edge since it supports  a greater number of platforms. But then again, Silverlight has all the power and resources of Microsoft behind it, and it's ideal for Windows Phone development.

### Comparison

For a comparison, here's what you get by each toolkit:

**Windows Presentation Foundation**:

- The power and resources of Microsoft
- Ideal for creating new Desktop Applications
- Eye candy
- Awesome API
- XAML, best way to separate design from logic
- Create Apps for the Cloud (but they only work on Windows with .NET though)
- Windows Phone can run a subset of WPF

**Windows Forms**:

- Used to possess the power and resources of Microsoft, now WPF has that
- Ideal for maintaining legacy applications
- A well-trained workforce, if you're an entrepreneur
- Pretty mature API
- Supports more platforms than WPF (through Mono)

**Java FX**:

- Create Apps for the Cloud
- Backed by Oracle
- Pretty nice API
- Cross-platform, runs on most PCs, smart phones are a problem.

**Silverlight**:

- Create Apps for the Cloud
- Backed by Microsoft
- Pretty awesome API
- XAML
- Cross-platform, runs on Mac and PC, runs on Windows Phone.

**GTK#**:

- Cross-platform, runs on most PCs, runs on no smart phone.
- Backed by the Open-Source world
- Endorsed by Mono
- Ideal for creating Apps for Gnome.

**Swing**:

- Cross-platforms, runs on most PCs, smart phones are a problem.
- Pretty mature
- Ideal for creating 2D games, using Java2D

### Conclusion

As you say:

> While my main aim is to create the app, obviously I'd like to learn something useful while doing so rather than picking up skills with something that's never going to be seen on a project at work.

Well, the frameworks you are most likely to see at work (if you don't for mainstream companies like Microsoft, Oracle, Google etc. ) are Windows Forms and WPF. At least that's what most companies use here. So those are what I recommend. JavaFX and Silverlight also look like they have potential and may be used in the near future.

Comment: You should mention MoonlightDesktop, it's no longer supported but has a nice subset of WPF's features and works out of the browser.  I haven't investigated it, but it appears to be work.

Comment: Update. Silverlight is dead in the meantime

Answer (score 8):

`WPF`. Best support for Windows. BTW, it's not obsolete.

Comment: It's also pretty similar to the Metro stuff. You can reuse your xaml and most architecture knowledge you gain from WPF even when you want to create metro style apps later.

Comment: There's the mono project's version of MoonlightDesktop.  Although its not supported it may have a suitable subset of WPF and it works out of the browser. Sadly, Mono doesn't realize the goldmine they have on their hands. They could easily turn it into the defacto graphics engine even if it's not as powerful as WPF.

Answer (score 1):

[Java FX 2.0](http://www.javafx.com) seems very promising and is now live if swing looks obsolete to you. Note that it has little in common with previous versions. See for example [this short comparison with swing](http://rkennke.wordpress.com/2011/10/11/javafx-2-the-new-swing/). And oracle said they plan to open the source.

Now it is fairly new so unlikely to be used in existing applications.

Comment: Given Java FX on the desktop seems to be built on/uses Swing, it is in trouble if Swing is obsolete.  (Swing is not obsolete, if anybody is confused about the matter.)

Comment: @AndrewThompson It is my understanding that Javafx 2.0 is not build on swing. They can (kind of) interoperate but are distinct. As an example, Javafx2 does not use the EDT but another specific thread. Previous versions might have been using swing, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

One option for you might be to create your application as HTML+Javascript and run it in your desktop application by embedding a browser engine (IE or something else). If you need native APIs, there are mechanisms to make these available to browser's Javascript code.

Comment: This almost never works. The write once run everywhere generally gives a horrible user experience on all supported platforms. HTML/JS are just too cumbersome to develop on.

Comment: You totally misunderstood. I didn't propose running it on every browser. I proposed embedding a specific browser engine (such as IE) and writing specifically for that. Whether development is cumbersome or not, is a matter of taste.

Comment: I just want to point out the sheer irony of this statement considering the world of node and electron that we now live in. Heh